# Table style in CSS

Tags: css, html-table, alignment

I currently have a little HTML page with following HTML/CSS codes inside.

```
<table style="width: 300px;">
    <tr style="height: 120px;">
        <td width="width: 100px;">
            <img src="images/lol/avatars/3.png" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
            <img src="images/score/3.png" style="display: block; background: #0c0c0c;" alt="3" title="5 üzerinden 3" />
        </td>
        <td width="width: 200px;">
            aaaa bbb  cccc  ddddd
            <h2 style="font-size: 1.6em; text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #0c0c0c; text-transform: none; color: #fcfcfc; ">Anil wrote.<h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The current output is:

[image]

(**Live example is here:** http://www.sobafire.com, under the right side of slider.)

The picture pretty much explains what I need, but I'll write them regardless.

1. The text at top (aaa bbb...) should be centered. Also, it should automatically keep centering itself if the text is long. (It shouldn't go upside or downside, it should be going upside by %50 and downside by %50.)
2. The "score" image with stars has a background color, which is "#0c0c0c". It should be the background color of entire bottom area, including "Anil wrote." text.
3. "Anil wrote." text should be aligned to right side.

I'll be glad if you can help me in this case.

Ps. There will be 3x TR in the current table, not a single like this. It won't make a difference but just a side note.

Ps 2. Live example added for users who would like to see it live.

Comment: Can't you just put the score and "Anil wrote" into their own row?

Comment: We aren't here to write your code for you. I'll help you in two ways: (1) You completely misunderstand how to use tables. Look up the difference between `tr` and `td`. (2) You don't need to use tables for this... CSS on `div`s and `span`s will work fine.

Comment: I agree with @JustinSatyr, (use `div` and `span`!). Also use css classes instead of inline styles.

Comment: @JustinSatyr, Doesn't TR is the row and TD is the column amount? I have been using tables for long, but never needed styles. They were just basic ones. 

Why do you prefer doing it with divs and spans instead of tables? Is it more professional way of doing this?

Comment: @c4urself, Yes. I agree, but I wanted to get it to work before move it to CSS.

Comment: You should use divs, tables are for raw data.

Comment: You're misunderstanding html/css. See @Harv's answer

Answer (score 2):

1. Use two TR for this, first row has the main image and the "aaaa bbb  cccc  ddddd"
   Second row has the stars and the "Anil wrote" info
   you will probably need a rowspan=2 for the first column.
   Sorry, forget about the rowspan.

Then if you have additional rows, just add them at the end, so you might have 4x TR and not 3.

1. Move all of your style items to a CSS style sheet
2. In general div is a better choice for layout, but you will find various points of view on this topic.
   Tables should be used for tablular data, not for layout.

Harv

Comment: Been trying to get it to work... Tried with divs, spans, tables. Almost 4th try but still the same. Things just get's messed when text has to be in the center. They either appear in the bottom, or outside of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another `<tr>` containing two `td`'s one with the rating and one with the 'Anil wrote' bit.

then you can add `text-align: center` to the comment td

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add another `<tr>` and `<td>` and use `valign:xxx;` and `align:xxx;`

CSS on divs and spans will work fine